# How to open a pdf in fullscreen view via command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line

I have been able to open a pdf document through command line by using:
`start test.pdf`

But I would like to open it in full screen mode via command line, does anyone have any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should do it.

```
start "" /max "c:\nameofpdf.pdf"
```

This has the advantage that it should work if the user is using other pdf document readers that are not adobe reader.  It should just use the default pdf reader on the machine.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't open in fullscreen mode for acrobat reader X

Does this work for a certain pdf reader?

Comment: Sorry, it does work here but I am on Reader 9.  One of the others must surely work.

Comment: @elleestcrimi I am confused as to why you marked this as an answer. I thought it wasn't working for you

Comment: I just downloaded the older adobe reader. I needed it for a presentation so I didn't mind using an older version as I couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: Well, it's a command-line of Windows or Adobe? I have tried on both, but it does not open in full screen mode for me.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the function of ""? I tried to open a PDF without this empty pair of quotes and it just opened a new full-screen command prompt, so I assume it tells the computer to use the PDF reader but I can't find any explanation as to why online. As is probably evident, I am running Windows.

Comment: The first argument is a window title, and the second is the command or file to open.  
`start "" "test space.avi"`  

http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Answer (score 9):

Windows 10:

`explorer.exe "file:\\path\to\file.pdf"`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which OS you are using. 
For Linux:

> evince -f "filename"

OR

> xdg-open "filename"

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the following with Adobe Reader 10:

```
start "" /max "C:\Program Files Xxxxx.exe" /A "pagemode=FullScreen" ".pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Acrobat.exe /A "zoom=1000" "C:\example.pdf"
```

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Please note you need to be in your acrobat directory to open the file.

Comment: When I add the /A it gives me an error saying that the file can't be found, then after clicking okay it shows the file normally. Yet no fullscreen

Comment: Looking through that document there isn't an option for fullscreen, so you might be SOL, unless you can combine some of the menu bar hiding to get the fullscreen effect.

Answer (score 0):

Before using command line just open *AcroRd32.exe/Acrobat.exe* and go to `Edit => Preferences => Full Screen` and uncheck on *Current document only*. Then you can use the command line as

```
start "" /max "C:\Program Files Xxxxx.exe" /A "pagemode=FullScreen" "yourfile direction and name.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the adobe folder, select `acrord32.exe` and provide it with path of `filename` you want to open. The adobe PDF viewer starts in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

To launch Foxit PDF Reader from cmd (Windows 10):
a)

```
START FoxitReader.exe "E:\..\myfile.pdf" /A zoom=106% page=1
```

b)

```
"<full path to foxit reader exe file>" "<full path to pdf file>" /A zoom=106% page=1
```