# Acrobat (reader): to open in full screen via command line on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, adobe, acrobat

I would like that my PDF document is opened in full screen mode via the command line on Windows. Something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 8.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" "pagemode=fullscreen" "myfile.pdf"
```

I do not think that the option `fullscreen` for the parameter `pagemode` exists.

I cannot set the document properties of my file `myfile.pdf` beforehand via *Document Properties* to open in full screen mode as the PDF file is generated by *LaTeXing* with a batch file. So everything has to be done via the Windows command line.

PS: The solutions proposed here:
[How to open a pdf in fullscreen view via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557920/how-to-open-a-pdf-in-fullscreen-view-via-command-line) do not work for Acrobat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for the same thing. i have been able to make the window fit my screen. No fullscreen though.
Example: `start "" /max "Acrobat path" /A "parameter=value" "PDF path"`

Your case:

```
start "" /max "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 8.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /A "zoom=100" "myfile.pdf"
```

PS: The scale value of 100 indicates a zoom value of 100%.

You can specify multiple parameters in a single URL. Separate each parameter with either an ampersand (&) or a pound (#) character.

Answer (score 0):

Test the below one,I've tested with Adobe Reader 10 start "" /max "C:\Program Files Xxxxx.exe" /A "pagemode=FullScreen" ".pdf"